# Which is the best way to join make 3 connections from 1 power supply source

Tags: adapter, connector

I have one Laptop Adapter of output 12v and 3A current.
I need to give the power supply to three cctv cmaeras from that adapter.

Currently i am just peeling the wires and joining all the three with insulating tapes. But it looks very dirty.

Is there ay connectors available where i have something like 7-8 pin connector i can join on adapter side and then

2 pin female coonector from each camera so that i just plugh them in and it should look tidy in case i need to unjoin it in future.

Just like we have our components in our computer motherboard

Comment: Probably better suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you might be near water, your local boating store should have something like [This 3-way 12V splitter](http://www.meritline.com/car-usb-charger-socket-325---p-33950.aspx?source=fghdac) (Radioshack, an automotive store or an RV store may also have something similar).

Given your voltage the automotive 12V adapters are an appropriate connector. However, you could also use the Molex 8981 Series connectors used on IDE disk drives, and just use the yellow and black wires.

Comment: I think the molex coonnectors are good to experiment with. Can i use same coonector of joining video signal wire as well. In my CCTV wire i have one power wire with sheild as grouund. One wire for video and one for audio and one for common ground for audio video. I was thinking of using 4 pins like power, ground , video, video ground and use coonectors like in Hard disk connectors with correcponding male  from camera side as well

Comment: @Moorage I would probably, personally, use a DC plug or molex connector for the power, and then your standard [RCA connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) for video and audio.